# Using roundMinutes in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to get the hour and minute and then round the minutes to the nearest 5.  I found the java Calendar class with the roundMinutes function here:  [enter link description here](http://www.rakeshv.org/docs/java/rakeshv/org/rakeshv/utils/Calendar.html#roundMinutes%28int,%20int%29)

How would I use this in code?  I have tried creating a Calendar object, a Date object, but nothing shows me this method to use.  Providing an example would be great!

Comment: Im not sure what API that is, but it isnt for the Standard Java Calendar class. Here is the Java 7 Documentation for Calendar. http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: While it doesn't directly answer your question, you'll probably want to use Joda Time whenever you're doing something with dates, not the built-in classes. http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I have previously answered a similar question where the OP wanted to round to the nearest quarter. Check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553964/how-to-round-time-to-the-nearest-quarter-in-java/3553994#3553994

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using [this](http://www.rakeshv.org/docs/java/rakeshv/org/rakeshv/utils/Calendar.html) `Calendar`. There is no `roundMinutes` in java's default calendar.

```
calendar.roundMinutes(5, Calendar.ROUND_UP) if you want 5:41 to become 5:45
calendar.roundMinutes(5, Calendar.ROUND_DOWN) if you want 5:41 to become 5:40

calendar.roundMinutes(5, Calendar.ROUND_AUTO) if you want 5:41 to become whatever the library thinks is normal.
```

See [`ROUND_DOWN`](http://www.rakeshv.org/docs/java/rakeshv/org/rakeshv/utils/Calendar.html)

Answer (score 2):

The following code rounds a given joda DateTime to 5 minutes and up

```
DateTime dt = timeEnded.minuteOfDay().roundCeilingCopy();

int minutes = dt.getMinuteOfHour();
int mod = minutes % 5;
int add = 5 - mod; //add this to our datetime

DateTime roundedTo5 = dt.plusMinutes(add);
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you are using the right `Calendar` class: `org.rakeshv.utils.Calendar`, assuming you are using the [custom Util jar that Rakesh created](http://src.rakeshv.org/java/jars/rvutils.jar).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the nearest 5 minutes but the following code will round to the next minute:

```
Date now = new Date();
Date nearestMinute = DateUtils.round(now, Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Perhaps you can proceed form there :D