# How to convert ( round ) epoch Time to nearest hour and day wrt IST (in Java)

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime, epoch

I have time in epoch format (as Java long variable).

I want to convert it to nearest hour as well as day with respect to Indian Standard Time (IST).

For example, if the epoch time is 1372618032000 (7/1/2013 12:17:12 AM IST), then i want to get 1372620600000 (7/1/2013 1:00:00 AM IST).

Similarly for day rounding.
I want to get 1372703400 (7/2/2013 12:00:00 AM IST). [Starting of the next day.]

I have gone through some documentation of Java Date, Java Calendar, Apache DateUtils, and JodaTime.

But i am not able to figure out what is the correct and best way to do this ?

NOTE: I want to round with respect to IST.

Comment: Maybe I am a bit late, but your question has been posed again and it has got a reasonable answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233236/in-java-how-do-we-round-off-time-to-nearest-hour-and-minute

Answer (score -1):

Certainly, you won't get a method to accomplish this.

Why not use [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)'s methods [`get(int field)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) and [`set(int field, int value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int%29). I'm positive that it can be done with these methods and a bit of rounding logic.