# JodaTime rounding down to nearest quarter of hour

Tags: java, jodatime

If the time is 10:36 I would like to round the time down to 10:30. If the time is 1050 I would like to round the time down to 10:45. etc... I am not sure how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Devise the mid point between the values (1045 and 1100) and determine if the current values falls closer to 1045 or 1100, adjust accordingly...

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
public static LocalTime roundToQuarterHour(LocalTime time) {
  int oldMinute = time.getMinuteOfHour();
  int newMinute = 15 * (int) Math.round(oldMinute / 15.0);
  return time.plusMinutes(newMinute - oldMinute);
}
```

(It may seem slightly overcomplicated since there's a `withMinuteOfHour` method, but keep in mind that we might round to 60, and `withMinuteOfHour(60)` is invalid.)

Comment: It seems he only wanted to round down so you should actually do this with `Math.floor`. In that case you don't have the problem of the 60 minutes.

Comment: Thank you for the hints without java.time. If you want to **round up** to the nearest Quarter, then you could use `Math.floor` in Combination with your code: `int newMinute = 15 * (int) Math.floor(oldMinute / 15.0);` and `return time.plusMinutes(newMinute - oldMinute +15)`

Comment: Doesn't this leave the seconds part of the original time?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. Decided to go this route and not introduce JodaTime. As found in this answer [How to round time to the nearest quarter hour in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553964/how-to-round-time-to-the-nearest-quarter-hour-in-java)

```
    long timeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();       
    long roundedtimeMs = Math.round( (double)( (double)timeMs/(double)(15*60*1000) ) ) * (15*60*1000);

    Date myDt = new Date(roundedtimeMs);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(myDt);

    if(calendar.before(new Date())) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -15);
    }

    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static LocalTime roundDown(LocalTime time, int toMinuteInterval) {
    int slotNo = (int)(time.getMillisOfDay() / ((double)toMinuteInterval * 60 * 1000));
    int slotsPerHour = 60 / toMinuteInterval;
    int h = slotNo / slotsPerHour;
    int m = toMinuteInterval * (slotNo % slotsPerHour);
    return new LocalTime(h, m);
}
```

Only works when toMinuteInterval is a factor of 60 (eg 10, 15, 30 etc).