# JAVA time rounding issue

Tags: java

Hope you can help  :-)

Struggling with an unusual rounding issue...

If time is "7:35 AM" the time should be "8:00 AM" - rounded to the nearest 30 minutes going forward...

If time is "7:20 AM" the time should be "7:30 AM"

Any ideas would be appreciated.

I have this but it rounds forwards and backwards.  Only need it to go forward:

```
private DateTime roundDate(final DateTime dateTime, final int minutes) {
    if (minutes < 1 || 60 % minutes != 0) 
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("minutes must be a factor of 60");
    }

    final DateTime hour = dateTime.hourOfDay().roundFloorCopy();
    final long millisSinceHour = new Duration(hour, dateTime).getMillis();
    final int roundedMinutes = ((int) Math.round(millisSinceHour / 60000.0 / minutes)) * minutes;

    System.out.println(hour.plusMinutes(roundedMinutes));

    return hour.plusMinutes(roundedMinutes);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code or you just asking for ideas? if so a simple if else would do this easily

Comment: Will post example above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use the Joda time library. In addition to the cool date helpers it provides, you should find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445573/jodatime-rounding-down-to-nearest-quarter-of-hour) a snipplet with code that does almost what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response but my method above does the same.  I need it to round forward ONLY...

Comment: Oh sorry. I didn't see the sample you posted in the meanwhile. I would suggest you  add 30 mn to hour if millisSinceHour is less than 30 * 60000

Comment: And add 60 mn if it is greater.